# How can I check the following conditions in c# using regular expression

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I've a condition like this

if I enter the text format as

9 - This should only allow numbers
s-  Should only allow special chars
a - should only allow alphabets
x - should allow alpha numerics

There may be combinations like, if I specify '9s' this should allow numbers and special chars,
'sa' - should allow alphabes and numerics etc..

How can I check these conditions using regular expressions using c#.

Thanks

Comment: nothing c# or .net specific in there!

Comment: what are you trying to do? or is this suppose to check certain fields upon making a selection from like a checklistbox?

Comment: I will be saving this format in the database, and will be allowing user to input only strings based on this format.

Answer (score 2):

You can translate these conditions into regex like this:

1. Start the regex with `^[`.
2. Then add one or more of the
   following:

   - Numbers: `\p{N}`
   - Special characters (i. e.
     non-alphanumerics): `\W`
   - Letters: `\p{L}`
   - Alphanumerics: `\w`
3. End the regex with `]+$`
4. Enclose the regex in a verbatim string.

So, for "only letters", it's `@"^[\p{L}]+$"`; for "numbers and special characters", it's `@"^[\p{N}\W]+$"` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot 'generate' regular expressions using C# unless you code for it. But you surely can go to a site like 'www.regexlib.com' to find and build the regular expressions you want.

Then you can execute your regular expressions using C# to validate user inputs. this [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308252) would give you the knowledge how to use C# for it.

Hope this helps, regards.